# .htaccess redirect www to non-www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've been trying this for a while. I want to redirect for example wwww.example.com to exmaple.com.

I've tried several snippets of code:

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^dansams\.co.uk [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.dansams.co.uk/$1 [R=permanent,nc,L]
```

....

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

There are more but none have worked. I have my .htaccess file in the root along with a folder called 'public_html'. All of my sites content is within that public_html folder. What's happening when I've tried all these different snippets of code, is when I try www.example.com, it's getting taken to the url:

```
www.example.com/public_html
```

This page displays some content but without css...and it's not all the index content either.

Any help with this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your DocumentRoot?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```